# error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: during test execution

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm starting to study selenium. trying to test the registration page. I created a registration page class in which I defined methods for checking registration. in the application class, I try to run a test, but it fails, an error appears

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    registration_page = require('./Registration_page');

class Application {

    constructor() {
        this.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser("chrome")
            .build();
        this.registrationPage = new registration_page.RegistrationPage(this.driver);
    }
    quit() {
        this.driver.quit();
    }

    registerNewCustomer(customer) {
        this.registrationPage.open();
        this.registrationPage.firstnameInput().sendKeys(customer.firstname);
        this.registrationPage.lastnameInput().sendKeys(customer.lastname);
        this.registrationPage.loginInput().sendKeys(customer.login);
        this.registrationPage.passwordInput().sendKeys(customer.password);
        this.registrationPage.passwordConfirmInput().sendKeys(customer.password);
    }
        app = new Application();
    app.registerNewCustomer([{firstname: 'Adam', lastname: 'Smith', login: `abcd${new Date().getTime()}`,password: 'asdfghjk', phone: '12345678'}]) 

exports.Application = Application;
```

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: each key must be a number of string; got undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing an array of objects instead of object to `registerNewCustomer` function.

Change

```js
app.registerNewCustomer([{
  firstname: 'Adam',
  lastname: 'Smith',
  login: `abcd${new Date().getTime()}`,
  password: 'asdfghjk',
  phone: '12345678'}
])
```

to

```js
customer = {
  firstname: 'Adam',
  lastname: 'Smith',
  login: `abcd${new Date().getTime()}`,
  password: 'asdfghjk',
  phone: '12345678'
};
app.registerNewCustomer(customer);
```

Additionally [sendKeys](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElementPromise.html) returns a promise so you can turn `registerNewCustomer` into an async function and catch any errors

```js
async registerNewCustomer(customer) {
  const page = this.registrationPage;
  await page.firstnameInput().sendKeys(customer.firstname);
  await page.lastnameInput().sendKeys(customer.lastname);
  await page.loginInput().sendKeys(customer.login);
  await page.passwordInput().sendKeys(customer.password);
  await page.passwordConfirmInput().sendKeys(customer.password);
}

customer = {
  firstname: 'Adam',
  lastname: 'Smith',
  login: `abcd${new Date().getTime()}`,
  password: 'asdfghjk',
  phone: '12345678'
};

app.registerNewCustomer(customer).catch(error => console.log(error));
```